# i looking for how make a refresh of tableView in pulling down?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, pull-to-refresh

if anyone can help me for make that (pull down to refresh):

source: http://cdn.iphone4jailbreak.org/wp-content/uploads/pull-to-refresh-jailbreak-app-iphone-4.jpg

Answer (score 1):

There are several resources to do that:

- [EGOTableViewPullRefresh](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh) - An open source project hosted on
  GitHub.
- [This tutorial](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/12/how-to-make-a-pull-to-reload-tableview-just-like-tweetie-2/) from [CocoaNetics](http://www.cocoanetics.com/).
- Included in the  [three20 library](https://github.com/facebook/three20)

Answer (score 0):

You can take all needful source codes here: [EGOTableViewPullRefresh](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh)

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass TTTableViewController and then delegate it to TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate.

```
- (id<TTTableViewDelegate>) createDelegate {    
    TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate *delegate = [[TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate alloc] initWithController:self];

    return [delegate autorelease];
}
```